# Android Studio : errors while building apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently updated my `Android Studio` to 2.1.1 and initially, the layout previews weren't working. There was a rendering problem. Then I changed the version of the `Android` to 23 (as was the solution to this problem i found in here). By this, thankfully rendering problem was solved.

But then another problem occurred in execution, and I found that .apk file is not generated.
And it gave **FileNotFoundException** for app-debug-unaligned.apk

I even tried to build apk manually but it also didn't work.
It says "File `<MyProjectPath>\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk`can not be found". 
apk folder is generated but its empty.
Please help !

Comment: You have to pay attention to where those builds are being written.  Signed and unsigned go to different place.

Comment: hey, thanks for helping. Actually it can not find the file <Project path>\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk

Comment: apk folder is generated inside outputs but its empty

Answer (score 0):

If useing library or module go to gradle and check dependencies for repeated compile.

For example

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'//  1
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'//    2
```

I hope help...

Comment: hello, I am just new to Android and sorry didn't get what you want to say. But my dependencies look like :                                `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:
>        First close your android studio then open to it. then clean your project, then rebuild project and then run your project.
>       hope it will work